# Problem to stop Auto Bot to registertration form

Tags: php

Auto bot is registering dummy users to my website. Today, I have implemented Captcha with additions of two numbers and store the result in SESSION variable. Only human can understand it and proceed with registration process. But I'm really confused that same bot is parsing the SESSION variable and entering correct value of addition of two numbers and get registered in the website with dummy user.

Is there any other feasible method to stop this bot to register dummy users?

I'm using Zen cart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [reCaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha). It is most likely a more advanced solution to your CAPTCHA issue.

Comment: Most captcha solutions fail now-a-days. I'll recommend recaptcha.

Comment: Is it easy to implement with PHP ?

Answer (score 0):

Use reCaptcha or other anti-bot solutions searchable by google

Answer (score 0):

I once added some simple JavaScript code to add an additional parameter to the form wich is only executed when the client has JavaScript enabled. Bots often don't have JS support.

An other solution would be to add a number of seconds a user was on the page before sending the form. Bots will send it immediately after the first request without delay.

An other thing I did once was that I checked the clients IP address and if it was from an other country than my own the user has to solve the captcha.

Also changing the names of the parameter is helpful.

And sending an individual hash to each form GET request and checking it when the POST arrives.

Comment: I feel the bot is intelligent in that way. It is executing JS code.